# Problems Correction of "Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory For Computer Science and Machine Learning "'

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, computer-science, mathematics-education, machine-learning

Where I can find the problems correction of this book " Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory For Computer Science and Machine Learning "